# gson parsing json data, how do i access different different entries of data from json array after parsing?

Tags: java, json, gson

Here is my code for parsing:

```
public static void main(String args) throws Exception {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    // 1. JSON to Java object, read it from a file.
    movieData allMovies = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("apiData.json"), movieData.class);

}
```

the apiData.json has data such as titles, descriptions, rating and other info on different movies:

```
"id": 157336,
  "original_title": "Interstellar",
  "original_language": "en",
  "title": "Interstellar",
  "backdrop_path": "\/xu9zaAevzQ5nnrsXN6JcahLnG4i.jpg",
  "popularity": 11.880841,
  "vote_count": 5628,
  "video": false,
  "vote_average": 8.11
```

Now my problem is that, say if I want to print out a list of movies with a string "THE" in the original_title filed, how do I access all the original_title fields automatically to check for the string? What exactly do I get with the last line in my code gson.fromJson? Is it an array called allMovies with objects of the movieData.class?

Answer (score 0):

You need get List of movies first by following

```
List<Movie> movieList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<List<Movie>>(){}.getType());
```

Then you can iterate "movieList" to get what exactly you want

Comment: should I add this as a new line or replace my existing fromJson line?